# Ubuntu 12.10: package manager is broken (I think)

Tags: 12.10, apt, package-management

Please note: I'm a newbie with Ubuntu, only just beginning to get a grasp on terminal, etc.

Whenever I try to install anything using terminal, with

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

it works fine until I have confirmed additional disk space will be used.

After it has fetched all the necessary files and unpacked them, I get a long list starting with

```
dpkg: error processing [...]
```

And it ends with

```
Processing was halted because there weE: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an 
errorcode (1)
```

I already googled for a solution quite a bit but can't find anyone with the exact same issue.

Also, I don't know if it has anything to do with it, but I tried to get some additional plugins for an application I installed through software center and it gave me an error message saying

> "An unhandlable error occured: 
>   There seems to be a programming error in aptdaemon, the software that allows you to install/remove software and to perform other package management related tasks."

Here's the full error log: http://pastebin.com/9YJSrf4a

```
181 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/358 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: error processing libkrb5-3:amd64 (--configure):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64:
 libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 depends on libkrb5-3 (= 1.10.1+dfsg-4+nmu1); however:
  Package libkrb5-3:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcurl3-gnutls:amd64:
 libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 depends on libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.10+dfsg~); however:
  Package libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcups2:amd64:
 libcups2:amd64 depends on libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.10+dfsg~); however:
  Package libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libcups2:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgtk2.0-0:amd64:
 libgtk2.0-0:amd64 depends on libcups2 (>= 1.6.2); however:
  Package libcups2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libgtk2.0-0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of chromium-browser:
 chromium-browser depends on libcups2 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcups2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 chromium-browser depends on libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.6.dfsg.2); however:
  Package libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 chromium-browser depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0); however:
  Package libgtk2.0-0:amd64 is not configured yet.
 chromium-browser depends on libkrb5-3 (>= 1.6.dfsg.2); however:
  Package libkrb5-3:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing chromium-browser (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of chromium-browser-l10n:
 chromium-browser-l10n depends on chromium-browser (>= 31.0.1650.63-0ubuntu0.13.04.1~20131204.1); however:
  Package chromium-browser is not configured yet.
 chromium-browser-l10n depends on chromium-browser (= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcups2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libcupsfilters1:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcupsimage2:amd64:
 libcupsimage2:amd64 depends on libcups2 (= 1.6.2-1ubuntu5); however:
  Package libcups2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libcupsimage2:amd64 depends on libcupsfilters1 (>= 1.0~b1); however:
  Package libcupsfilters1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libcupsimage2:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgs9:
 libgs9 depends on libcups2 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcups2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libgs9 depends on libcupsimage2 (>=No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                  No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcupsimage2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libgs9 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ghostscript:
 ghostscript depends on libgs9 (= 9.07~dfsg2-0ubuntu3.1); however:
  Package libgs9 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing ghostscript (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-filters:
 cups-filters depends on libcups2 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcups2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 cups-filters depends on libcupsfilters1 (>= 1.0~b1); however:
  Package libcupsfilters1:amd64 is not configured yet.
 cups-filters depends on libcupsimage2 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcupsimage2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 cups-filters depends on ghostscript (>= 9.02~); however:
  Package ghostscript is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing cups-filters (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libsane-hpaio:
 libsane-hpaio depends on libcups2 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcups2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libsane-hpaio (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ghostscript-cups:
 ghostscript-cups depends on libcups2 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcups2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 ghostscript-cups depends on libcupsimage2 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcupsimage2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 ghostscript-cups depends on ghostscript (>= 8.64~dfsg-8); however:
  Package ghostscript is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing ghostscript-cups (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcupscgi1:amd64:
 libcupscgi1:amd64 depends on libcups2 (= 1.6.2-1ubuntu5); however:
  Package libcups2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libcupscgi1:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcupsmime1:amd64:
 libcupsmime1:amd64 depends on libcups2 (= 1.6.2-1ubuntu5); however:
  Package libcups2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libcupsmime1:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcupsppdc1:amd64:
 libcupsppdc1:amd64 depends on libcups2 (= 1.6.2-1ubuntu5); however:
  Package libcups2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libcupsppdc1:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-daemon:
 cups-daemon depends on libcups2 (= 1.6.2-1ubuntu5); however:
  Package libcups2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 cups-daemon depends on libcupsmime1 (>= 1.5.0); however:
  Package libcupsmime1:amd64 is not configured yet.
 cups-daemon depends on libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.10+dfsg~); however:
  Package libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing cups-daemon (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-client:
 cups-client depends on libcups2 (= 1.6.2-1ubuntu5); however:
  Package libcups2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 cups-client depends on libcupsimage2 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcupsimage2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing cups-client (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-ppdc:
 cups-ppdc depends on libcups2 (>= 1.6.2); however:
  Package libcups2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 cups-ppdc depends on libcupsppdc1 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcupsppdc1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing cups-ppdc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups:
 cups depends on libcups2 (= 1.6.2-1ubuntu5); however:
  Package libcups2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 cups depends on libcupscgi1 (>= 1.4.2); however:
  Package libcupscgi1:amd64 is not configured yet.
 cups depends on libcupsimage2 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcupsimage2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 cups depends on libcupsmime1 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcupsmime1:amd64 is not configured yet.
 cups depends on libcupsppdc1 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcupsppdc1:amd64 is not configured yet.
 cups depends on cups-daemon (>= 1.6.2-1ubuntu5); however:
  Package cups-daemon is not configured yet.
 cups depends on ghostscript (>= 9.02~); however:
  Package ghostscript is not configured yet.
 cups depends on cups-client (>= 1.6.2-1ubuntu5); however:
  Package cups-client is not configured yet.
 cups depends on cups-ppdc; however:
  Package cups-ppdc is not configured yet.
 cups depends on cups-filters (>= 1.0.24-3~); however:
  Package cups-filt
dpkg: error processing cups (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of printer-driver-hpcups:
 printer-driver-hpcups depends on libcups2 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcups2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 printer-driver-hpcups depends on libcupsimage2 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcupsimage2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 printer-driver-hpcups depends on ghostscript-cups; however:
  Package ghostscript-cups is not configured yet.
 printer-driver-hpcups depends on cups (>= 1.4.0) | cupsddk; however:
  Package cups is not configured yet.
  Package cupsddk is not installed.
 printer-driver-hpcups depends on cups; however:
  Package cups is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing printer-driver-hpcups (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of hplip:
 hplip depends on libcups2 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcups2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 hplip depends on libsane-hpaio (= 3.13.3-1ubuntu0.1); however:
  Package libsane-hpaio is not configured yet.
 hplip depends on printer-driver-hpcups (= 3.13.3-1ubuntu0.1); however:
  Package printer-driver-hpcups is not configured yet.
 hplip depends on cups (>= 1.1.20); however:
  Package cups is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing hplip (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of printer-driver-postscript-hp:
 printer-driver-postscript-hp depends on hplip (>= 3.13.3-1ubuntu0.1); however:
  Package hplip is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing printer-driver-postscript-hp (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of printer-driver-foo2zjs:
 printer-driver-foo2zjs depends on libcups2 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcups2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing printer-driver-foo2zjs (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of printer-driver-c2esp:
 printer-driver-c2esp depends on libcups2 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcups2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 printer-driver-c2esp depends on libcupsfilters1 (>= 1.0~b1); however:
  Package libcupsfilters1:amd64 is not configured yet.
 printer-driver-c2esp depends on libcupsimage2 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcupsimage2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing printer-driver-c2esp (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libindicator7:
 libindicator7 depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.18); however:
  Package libgtk2.0-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libindicator7 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libappindicator1:
 libappindicator1 depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.20.0); however:
  Package libgtk2.0-0:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libappindicator1 depends on libindicator7 (>= 0.4.90); however:
  Package libindicator7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libappindicator1 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcanberra-gtk0:amd64:
 libcanberra-gtk0:amd64 depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0); however:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

  Package libgtk2.0-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libcanberra-gtk0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-session-canberra:
 gnome-session-canberra depends on libcanberra-gtk0; however:
  Package libcanberra-gtk0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing gnome-session-canberra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcurl3:amd64:
 libcurl3:amd64 depends on libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.10+dfsg~); however:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

  Package libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libcurl3:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcurl3-nss:amd64:
 libcurl3-nss:amd64 depends on libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.10+dfsg~); however:
  Package libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libcurl3-nss:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libfreerdp-plugins-standard:amd64:
 libfreerdp-plugins-standard:amd64 depends on libcups2 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libcups2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libfreerdp-plugins-standard:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgail18:amd64:
 libgail18:amd64 depends on libgtk2.0-0 (= 2.24.17-0ubuntu2); however:
  Package libgtk2.0-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libgail18:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmlt5:
 libmlt5 depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0); however:
  Package libgtk2.0-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libmlt5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmlt++3:
 libmlt++3 depends on libmlt5; however:
  Package libmlt5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libmlt++3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of liboauth0:amd64:
 liboauth0:amd64 depends on libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2); however:
  Package libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing liboauth0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libufe-xidgetter0:
 libufe-xidgetter0 depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0); however:
  Package libgtk2.0-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libufe-xidgetter0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libwxgtk2.8-0:amd64:
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                               libwxgtk2.8-0:amd64 depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0); however:
  Package libgtk2.0-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libwxgtk2.8-0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of melt:
 melt depends on libmlt5; however:
  Package libmlt5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing melt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-mlt5:
 python-mlt5 depends on libmlt++3; however:
  Package libmlt++3 is not configured yet.
 python-mlt5 depends on libmlt5; however:
  Package libmlt5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python-mlt5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of samba-common-bin:
 samba-common-bin depends on libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.10+dfsg~); however:
  Package libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 samba-common-bin depends on libkrb5-3 (>= 1.10+dfsg~); however:
  Package libkrb5-3:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing samba-common-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of smbclient:
 smbclient depends on libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.10+dfsg~); however:
  Package libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 smbclient depends on libkrb5-3 (>= 1.10+dfsg~); however:
  Package libkrb5-3:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing smbclient (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libsmbclient:amd64:
 libsmbclient:amd64 depends on libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.10+dfsg~); however:
  Package libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libsmbclient:amd64 depends on libkrb5-3 (>= 1.10+dfsg~); however:
  Package libkrb5-3:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libsmbclient:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of vlc-nox:
 vlc-nox depends on libsmbclient (>= 3.0.24); however:
  Package libsmbclient:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing vlc-nox (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of vlc-plugin-notify:
 vlc-plugin-notify depends on vlc-nox (= 2.0.8-0ubuntu0.13.04.1); however:
  Package vlc-nox is not configured yet.
 vlc-plugin-notify depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.8.0); however:
  Package libgtk2.0-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing vlc-plugin-notify (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of vlc:
 vlc depends on vlc-nox (= 2.0.8-0ubuntu0.13.04.1); however:
  Package vlc-nox is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing vlc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of vlc-plugin-pulse:
 vlc-plugin-pulse depends on vlc-nox (= 2.0.8-0ubuntu0.13.04.1); however:
  Package vlc-nox is not configured yet.No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

dpkg: error processing vlc-plugin-pulse (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of whoopsie:
 whoopsie depends on libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2); however:
  Package libcurl3:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing whoopsie (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apt-transport-https:
 apt-transport-https depends on libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.29.0-1ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing apt-transport-https (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openssh-client:
 openssh-client depends on libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.10+dfsg~); however:
  Package libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing openssh-client (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 libkrb5-3:amd64
 libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64
 libcurl3-gnutls:amd64
 libcups2:amd64
 libgtk2.0-0:amd64
 chromium-browser
 chromium-browser-l10n
 libcupsfilters1:amd64
 libcupsimage2:amd64
 libgs9
 ghostscript
 cups-filters
 libsane-hpaio
 ghostscript-cups
 libcupscgi1:amd64
 libcupsmime1:amd64
 libcupsppdc1:amd64
 cups-daemon
 cups-client
 cups-ppdc
 cups
 printer-driver-hpcups
 hplip
 printer-driver-postscript-hp
 printer-driver-foo2zjs
 printer-driver-c2esp
 libindicator7
 libappindicator1
 libcanberra-gtk0:amd64
 gnome-session-canberra
 libcurl3:amd64
 libcurl3-nss:amd64
 libfreerdp-plugins-standard:amd64
 libgail18:amd64
 libmlt5
 libmlt++3
 liboauth0:amd64
 libufe-xidgetter0
 libwxgtk2.8-0:amd64
 melt
 python-mlt5
 samba-common-bin
 smbclient
 libsmbclient:amd64
 vlc-nox
 vlc-plugin-notify
 vlc
 vlc-plugin-pulse
 whoopsie
 apt-transport-https
 openssh-client
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)s.
```

Comment: plz post the full error report.

Comment: Try this `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a`, and report back.  This may take a long time.

Comment: Avinash, I put the error log in the comments

Mitch, I did what you said and it gave me back 

`/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: ca-certificates is broken or not fully installed`

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
sudo dpkg --purge ca-certificates
```

Then run :

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

*If yet not solved :*

Run

```
gksudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

In the resulting text document, search for the sections start with `Package : ca-certificates`. Then delete the whole section starts with that.

Then run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a && sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Computer says:dpkg: error processing package ca-certificates (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ca-certificates